# Recommend a Visual Studio FTP deployment plug-in

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, ftp

we've recently stumbled across the excellent [Dispatch for ASP](http://www.dispatchasp.net/) FTP deployment plug in. It looks great apart from one thing: It doesn't work with **Visual Studio 2010**, at least for us, anyway. (It's *supposed* to work fine.)

(Yes, we've tried everything: We've managed to get Dispatch working for another FTP site, but not the main one we regularly deploy to. We *have* managed to connect to our main site through FileZilla FTP, so the site itself is configured correctly. All settings have been triple checked, but the software still throws up weird errors (always to do with its internal libraries).)

So does anyone know of any other comparable FTP-based, deployment plug-in for Visual Studio?

**Here's what Dispatch does (and so any suggested replacement must do):**

- Monitor any altered files
  in the project. When a file is
  changed, it's added to a list of
  files to be deployed.
- To deploy these
  files to the live site, all we need
  to do is click "Upload" and the plugin will
  connect via FTP to our live site and
  upload the *selected* files.
- We can filter out
  any filenames we don't want to be
  monitored/uploaded (e.g. *.cs or
  web.config or /Images/*, etc.)

I think that's all the features that we need. Thanks for any suggestions!

Note: If you're wondering why we need such a service, it's because we deploy many site changes over the course of a single day. Publishing the entire project to a folder, zipping it up, then FTPing that zip file, only to have to unzip it, and then install the entire project into the live wwwroot takes far too long. With Dispatch you're able to upload individual files in a single click.

Comment: You say you were able to get it working on another FTP site, but you're positive that it isn't the FTP server causing issues?  Was the other FTP site (the one that worked) running the same server software?  It is possible to have certain FTP servers not work with certain FTP clients.

Comment: It was indeed and issue with the Rebex FTP library and IIS7.5. You can read about it here: http://forum.rebex.net/questions/279/unable-to-connect-over-ftp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much back and forth between me and the creator of Dispatch, we managed to narrow down the problem to the library he was using ([Rebex FTP](http://www.rebex.net/default.aspx)). I posted a question about the issue on the **Rebex** forums, and it was revealed that their software might have a bug with **IIS7.5**. They suggested a quick hack/fix, which I tested and discovered worked.

Mr. Dispatch then quickly implemented this hack/fix into his software, and lo! I had a fully working copy of Dispatch... **So no need for a replacement any more!**

(And from what I've seen, there isn't even any other plug-ins offering this functionality, so it's just as well.)

Comment: Just for record - we DO test Rebex FTP with IIS 7.5. In fact it's one of the configurations that is tested by automated test suite every night. If you have steps to reproduce this problem would it be possible to drop me a note to support@rebex.net? It can be easily fixed by turning off the FTP feature autodetection and it would be nice to do it automatically if possible. For details see http://forum.rebex.net/questions/279/unable-to-connect-over-ftp . Thanks, Martin.

Comment: Whoops. Corrected, sorry about that. I actually asked that question you linked to (you can find the same link higher up on this page) but I misread one of the responses. I'll email you with regards to helping you solve this.

Comment: I've got your email and forwarded it to the developer responsible for the component. He'll contact you and will try to resolve it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Dispatch sounds awesome.  Too bad it seems to be shut down at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update - Dispatch does not work with VS 2013 so if you have VS 2012 with Dispatch installed, Keep it. Also the website is gone so it looks like all development has ceased. I have been using Dispatch since VS2005 and it has been great for just sending single files up when I need to. Too bad it is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I built a very simple one for myself - you right click the file in Solution Explorer and it then uploads that file based on a settings file you create.

It's super crude but it works and the source is there to make it better if you like -

https://github.com/garazy/vs-2017-ftp-upload

Answer (score 0):

Big enhancements have been added to VS2008, VS2010, VS2012. Below is the article. I found that Microsoft did all the above while I was searching. Since this came up high in what I was searching, thought should share this knowledge.

[Deploy a Web Application Project Using One-Click Publish Without Web Deploy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd434211%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)